# how to use start and end in css position reletive or others?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to use multiple languages in my nextjs project and MUI library, and I m setting my body element of my project direction using locale.

```
  const App = (props: MyAppProps) => {
    const {
        Component,
        emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache,
        pageProps,
    } = props;

    const router = useRouter()
    const { locale } = router;
    

    return (
        <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={getTheme(theme)}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <GlobalStyles styles={{
                    body:{
                    backgroundColor:getTheme(theme).palette.Background.background,
                    direction:locale==="fa"?"rtl":"ltr"
                    }
                }}/>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        </CacheProvider>
    );
};
```

and that works fine with the text-align property
but I have a problem with positioning my elements because there are right, left, bottom, top properties in positioning, and there isn't a start and end property. for example:

```
 width:50px;
 height:50px
 position: relative;
 left:2px
```

my element with the position above, I want to position 2px from left in RTL directional language like Persian but I want to position it 2px from right in LTR directional language such as the English Language. it is usually done with start and end properties but in css i dont know because there isnt sutch a thing in position property.so my question is how can I position the elements base of start and end?

Comment: Your question is vague and your sample code is not compatible with your question, please change it then add the section of your code which is your main concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to understand your code, But question is related to CSS that's why I am providing you some idea.
Let's you have a element `<div id="element" class="{{ direction:locale==='fa'?'rtl':'ltr' }}">Your contents</div>`

Now, put this css in your style page->

```
#element.rtl {
 left: 2px;
}
#element.ltr {
 right: 2px;
}
```

Hope this will help you. If not, comment here.

Answer (score 1):

display Put your element in flex mode and use the justify-content, ... capabilities.
go to
[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set position relative to div element and lest or right position to nested div element.

Structure your HTML similar to this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="top left"></div>
  <div class="top right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container > * {
  position: absolute;
}

.left {
  left: 2px;
}

.right {
  right: 2px;
}
```